# Grails invokeMethod doesn't work

Tags: grails

I have 2 method which get the same params:

```
 void removeJob(def user,def company,String job){}
 void addJob(def user,def company,String job){}
```

I want to use the invokeMethod() but I'm not sure how.
I try:

```
def methodName = selectedChange[2]=='true'?'add':'remove'
roleService.invokeMethod(methodName+'Job',[userSelected,      selectedCompany,selectedChange[1]])
```

But I got errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the method dynamically using a GString for the method name:

```
String methodName = selectedChange[2] == 'true' ? 'add' : 'remove'
roleService."${methodName + 'Job'}"(userSelected, selectedCompany, selectedChange[1])
```

This also works with properties, e.g.

```
String propertyName = 'fooCount'
int count = person."$propertyName"
```